# Trying to build a basic React-Redux click switcher but nothing is displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The app is just supposed to display 'Hello' and when you click on it, switch to 'Goodbye', but it won't render 'Hello'. I've set default state, connected everything, etc. but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import "./styles.css";

const switcheroo = () => {
  return {
    type: 'SWITCH'
  };
};

const switchReducer = (state = {value: 'Hello'}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SWITCH':
      return { ...state, value: 'Goodbye' };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

class ClickMachine extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { value, switcheroo } = this.props;
    return(
      <div >
        <p onClick={switcheroo}>{value}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  value: state.value,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  switcheroo: () => dispatch(switcheroo()),
});

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClickMachine);


const store = createStore(switchReducer);

class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ClickMachine />
      </Provider>
    );
  };
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<AppWrapper />, rootElement);
```

My CodeSandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k29r3928z7 and I have the following dependencies:

- react
- react-dom
- react-redux
- redux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you've not assigned the connect function to a component, without which redux won't be associated with the ClickMachine Component
just change this line, it will work

```
 ClickMachine = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClickMachine);
```

Sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/4x2pr03489